# Sending CloudFront requests into SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-sqs

Is it possible to configure CloudFront to send incoming HTTP requests straight into SQS, without using EC2 or AWS Lambda for example?

I am looking for the same kind of integration between API Gateway -> SQS, except with CloudFront.

Comment: Can I ask... _WHY_ do you wish to do this? It seems a bit odd since CloudFront is designed to provide a faster response to requests, but your requirement would not involve responding to a request. Can you describe your actual use-case? There might be alternatives that we can then recommend.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein It's not possible to set WAF with Shield Advanced on API Gateway. So I must use CloudFront. Might as well save on costs if I can remove API Gateway.

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible. You would need to use a Lambda function to do that.

Answer (score 0):

As of today (August 2023), there's no direct integration between Amazon CloudFront and Amazon SQS.

However, you can use CloudFront -> API Gateway -> SQS.

To get started, have a look at this [AWS Solutions Construct, showing how to integrate API Gateway with SQS](https://go.aws/3qkPQAk) (this is a CDK construct, however, it provides all the details necessary to derive the details for other deployment methods).

Once you have set this up, you can use the API Gateway resource as a CloudFront origin.